# How can I encapsulate the AddHandler and RemoveHandler in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have a few events in a class, some of which are initially given handlers (Subs within the class) using AddHandler in the constructor, others are not assigned a handler.

All the handlers are generally of the same form:

```
Private Sub MyEventHandlingSub()

    ' Do some work

    If (some condition has been met) Then
        ' 1: Send an event to this this object (Me) to indicate condition has been met
        ' 2: Remove this as a handler (this handler handles just one of many events)
        ' 3: Add one or more new handlers (not necessarily handling the same event)
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to encapsulate these functions into a 'rules' object somehow so that I can initialise my class with these 'rules'.

How do I encapsulate these functions into 'rules'?

Comment: why you need to do that?

Comment: To reduce code duplication and to separate out the 'rules'. I could have a class for each event I want to handle, but this would still lead to code duplication as each separate class would still have the same structure.  My ultimate goal is to implement an [extended state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Extended_states).  Upon reaching a certain condition the state will change and a new set of event handlers (states) will take over.  Perhaps there is an alternative implementation? I just dont want to write a new class for each state as there could be thousands of them.

Comment: Ah, I see, but it seems very difficult to do so

Comment: If your class is raising events and handling them with its own instance methods, why use the event pattern at all?

Comment: At the time I was new to events in VB and went a little crazy with them :D.  In the end I went for a totally different simpler solution.